# TableView in a popup Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, popup

please can someone tell me if i can put a tableView in a popup View. I have been using a function called showStandardDialog from **PopupDialog**, here some code:

```
func showStandardDialog(a: String, b:String) {

    // Prepare the popup
    let title = "¡ INFORMACIÓN !"
    let message = "this is " +  a + "and this is " + b 

    // Create the dialog
    let popup = PopupDialog(title: title, message: message, buttonAlignment: .horizontal, transitionStyle: .zoomIn, gestureDismissal: true) {
        print("Completed")
    }

    // Create first button
    let buttonOne = CancelButton(title: "CANCEL") {
    }

    // Create second button
    let buttonTwo = DefaultButton(title: "OK") {
    }

    // Add buttons to dialog
    popup.addButtons([buttonOne, buttonTwo])

    // Present dialog
    self.present(popup, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

But i don´t know how i can use this same function and library sending a list.

Thanks to all :)

Answer (score 1):

PopupDialog is a 3rd party lib and if you need something super custom you should consider doing it yourself.

That being said if you want to use this lib, take a look at how the RatingViewController is done [in the examples](https://github.com/Orderella/PopupDialog/blob/master/Example/PopupDialog/RatingViewController.swift):

```
//
//  RatingViewController.swift
//  PopupDialog
//
//  Created by Martin Wildfeuer on 11.07.16.
//  Copyright © 2016 CocoaPods. All rights reserved.
//
import UIKit

class RatingViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var cosmosStarRating: CosmosView!

    @IBOutlet weak var commentTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        commentTextField.delegate = self
        view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(endEditing)))
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @objc func endEditing() {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
}

extension RatingViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        endEditing()
        return true
    }
}
```

There is no reason why you couldn't add a TableView in the xib and in the ViewController include the necessary delegate and data source.